# I need to load a 1GB file with a GWT application. Is it possible? Maybe if I run the application locally only?

Tags: java, gwt, file-access

I am going to start a new GWT project but I will need it to parse big files (1 GB text files). Is it possible to do that? It is not necessary to make it accessible in internet but yes locally in a browser... Or maybe it should be a GWT standalone application?

Thanks!
Patricio

Comment: Yes it is possible in the Turing Machine sense - yet I would suggest parsing on the server side and only passing relevant parts to the GWT client...

Comment: Might be doable in the browser using [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader); depending whether the file is already accessible on the web or not. Don't you think @AndersR.Bystrup ?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer I agree that it is possible, and even feasible, but I'm questioning whether it's a good idea - especially the words "parse" and "1 Gb" leads me to think of an exploding memory footprint of the browser instance.

Comment: It is possible, but the browser keeps on throwing script taking a lot of time to complete alert. I've worked with 3Mb files, parsing, ie., around 30000 records from the DB.